# Multiple exclusion with aws cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I need to implement a service that will return a list of items randomly sorted but excluding a set of know items.

I have an index in aws cloudsearch with these items in documents and was thinking of using an expression to sort them randomly and using an filter using something like (not (_id: [123, 32, 321, 456])) to exclude the items I don't want. But my exclusion list may have thousands and thousands of items.

Does this expression support this amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not support 'thousands and thousands'. The issue is that queries are GET requests, and servers have limits on how long a URL can be.

For CloudSearch, that limit appears to be 5532 characters; go beyond that, and you'll get an error with the HTTP status code `413 FULL HEAD`. I determined that experimentally by making requests to CloudSearch where I changed the length of my query string; I don't see it in their docs anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While @alexroussos is correct that you are being limited by the size of a GET request, it is not true that you cannot get around that limit, as CloudSearch accepts queries via POST also.

From the [CloudSearch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/submitting-search-requests.html):

> The maximum size of a search request submitted via GET is 8190 bytes, including the HTTP method, URI, and protocol version. You can submit larger requests using HTTP POST; however, keep in mind that large, complex requests take longer to process and are more likely to time out. For more information, see Tuning Search Request Performance in Amazon CloudSearch.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what @MikeFHay said, while CloudSearch does accept POSTs, it's not exactly made easy for you. The AWS SDK (at least for Java) doesn't use POSTs, and it looks like it won't be supported any time soon. The following won't be merged in because the cloudsearch aws sdk code is auto-generated, and they say it is a difficult feature to add.

[Pull Request to add POST](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/pull/697)

There's another library on github that we forked and modified to use POSTs instead of GETs for search requests. For anyone interested:

[cloudsearch client library](https://github.com/jsmitley/amazon-cloudsearch-client-java)